# Writing script and running in EC2 through aws cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I can create a EC2 instance in cloudformation. But I want to write a .sh script inside EC2 and running once when the instance comes up. Can anyone please guide me to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS::CloudFormation::Init and pass the shell commands directly (see first example) or, for example, write files (second example)

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyEc2Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "do_something": {
            "commands": {
              "foobar": {
                "command": "echo FOO > /etc/motd"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "Resources": {
    "MyEc2Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Metadata" : {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "do_something" : {
            "files" : {
              "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                  "#!/bin/sh\n",
                  "ls -al\n"
                ]]},
                "mode"  : "000755",
                "owner" : "root",
                "group" : "root"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a great deal of documentation available on using CloudFormation which can be used to invoke PowerShell cmdlets and bash commands using resource initialization routines.

One such feature is called as `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` and more details on in's usage is documented on [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html)

Comment: Thanks, do you have any link to understand  cfn-init, cfn-signal, cfn-get-metadata, and cfn-hup  in details ?

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if this indeed helped you set a direction of travel to solve this problem. One of the many ways to keep us motivated.